# Removing groups form user in Office 365 with powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I have a user who we removed though his email's are currently directed to his boss. I am looking for a script that will, in O365, remove him from all distro/security groups that he has currently connected. I was unable to find anything in my searching so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello new user. You need to attempt the problem yourself and - if you run into problems - post the code here for others to help you with the bits you get stuck on. I suggest you start [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx#BKMK_ManageUsers)

Comment: Thanks for the lack of assistance in that. Also due to being anew user I was unable to post that I had found a little of what I need and was able to put it together with what I had to make the script work. Maybe next time you could be a little less rude, I was never asking for someone to script it for me, just to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: My comments aren't rude, they are a statement of fact. You are a new user so the onus is on you to find out how to ask a question which makes sense and can have a concrete answer. Read this before posting next time: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And don't be such a cry baby in a public space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this as a ps1 file and then execute in the powershell connected to office 365 exchange

```
$DGs= Get-DistributionGroup | where { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | foreach {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -contains "user@domain.com"}

foreach( $dg in $DGs){
Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg -Member user@domain.com
}
```

e.g your user's primary smtp address is user@domain.com, then this script will remove the membership of this user from each mail enabled exchange distribution groups

Comment: Thank you, I actually found this and made the modifications needed. I appreciate the answer however.